# python manage.py migrate doesn't work on anaconda

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, anaconda

I am new to django; I am trying to finish my first project and I was able to start project but it fails migration. Here is the error code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "manage.py", line 10, in
>
> ```
> <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) 
>  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
> ```
>
> line 338, in
>
> ```
> execute_from_command_line utility.execute()
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 312, in execute django.setup()
>
> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 18, in
>   setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>
> File
>   "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\django\apps\registry.py", line
>   85, in populate app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)     File
>   "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\django\apps\config.py", line
>   127, in create "'%s' isn't a subclass of AppConfig." % entry) 
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
>   'django.contrib.admin.apps.AdminConfig' isn't a subclass of
>   AppConfig.

I even tried

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

but same error.

I am using Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)| and django==1.8

I should mention in order to start the project I had to use

```
python admin-py.exe startproject djangotutorial
```

because

```
python admin-py.py startproject djangotutorial
```

didn't work

I really appreciate any insight

Comment: Please review your formatting. This is barely readable.

Comment: Thanks, I tried reformating.  Please let me know if this readable

Comment: I am stuck on this step, I really appreciate it if you could help.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you made your project incorrectly. To start a project you use `django-admin startproject djangotutorial` and then you navigate to the folder. If the command doesn't work, then your django installation has a problem. Only after that can you use `python manage.py makemigrations`.

Comment: thanks, "django-admin startproject djangotutorial" fixed the problem.  However, after every shutdown, "python manage.py runserver" is no longer working showing the same error I wrote above.  In other words, I have to start creating the project all over again.  Is there a work-around?

Comment: Do you mean the shutdown of your server or of your Command Prompt? Also, do you have admin rights?

Comment: I run Command Prompt as an administrator but the above issue occurs both after shutdown of Command Prompt or the PC.

Comment: Are the folders for your django project not being created correctly?

Comment: In the folder where I have djngo project. I have:
Include (up to 95 header files, boost and greenlet), Lib(distutils, encodings, site-packages and py pyc files), Scripts (bat files, py pyc files, wheeel dll exe), djangotutorial (djangotutorial, db.sqlite3, manage.py), djangotutorial (__init__, urls, wsgi, settings)

Comment: Try creating it in a different folder. I.e. make a new folder C:\djangotutorial and then run django-admin startproject djangotutorial

Comment: the same problem after creating new folder.  I am actually a bit confused; do I have to repeat all steps every time I closes the Command Prompt or reset my PC.  Basically:
virtualenv .
pip install Django==1.8
django-admin startproject myproject
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
 python manage.py runserver

Can you please let me know how I should set the PATH (I am thinking maybe I am not doing it right).

Comment: Why are you installing Django every time? Just open up command prompt in a separate folder and type django-admin startproject myproject. You should only have to do this once..

Comment: I installed Pyhton 3 and tried the example there; I no longer have the error . Thanks

Comment: If you found this useful, it would be nice if you could accept this answer. Thanks