# dev_appserver.py not starting development server

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I've been following this tutorial here in an attempt to build an app on Google app engine:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-django-skeleton

I've hit a brick wall though in that when I run dev_appserver.py, 2 out of 3 servers run fine. But the development server just returns 500 errors.

The exact console output is the following:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/appengine-django-skeleton$ dev_appserver.py --port=9999 app.yaml
INFO     2015-12-15 15:50:11,507 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2015-12-15 15:50:11,691 sdk_update_checker.py:257] The SDK is up to date.
INFO     2015-12-15 15:50:11,807 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:60930
INFO     2015-12-15 15:50:11,993 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:9999
INFO     2015-12-15 15:50:11,993 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2015-12-15 15:50:16,395 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/appengine-django-skeleton/mysite/wsgi.py", line 29, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/appengine-django-skeleton/lib/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/appengine-django-skeleton/lib/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/appengine-django-skeleton/lib/django/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/appengine-django-skeleton/lib/django/django/apps/config.py", line 131, in create
    "'%s' isn't a subclass of AppConfig." % entry)
ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.contrib.admin.apps.AdminConfig' isn't a subclass of AppConfig.
```

And I'm guessing that the key line here is

```
ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.contrib.admin.apps.AdminConfig' isn't a subclass of AppConfig.
```

No code changes have been made to the file from github. Only the configuration changes listed on the github page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601560/python-manage-py-migrate-doesnt-work-on-anaconda check this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have manged to solve this problem by installing all the modules required on  `virtualenv` not inside the `lib` directory. After cloning the repository, run this command.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: This worked for me too. In my case I also needed to upgrade pip first using 'sudo pip install -U pip' due to setuptools being out of date and causing compilation errors when installing django.

Comment: @Adam did you have any idea on configuring django database in settings.py while django running on gae.